# How does Eclipse identify Keywords

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse - Code Assist, I want to know how to update the Eclipse code Assist.

ie. Keywords like instanceof , for , etc. Using Ctrl + Space will automatically insert corresponding words in Workspace.

If i want to create new Language support means. What should i do for keywords?

Comment: If you want support for new languages in eclipse download eclipse plugin for that language and you will get it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For support content Assist for a new language, I would recommend **[XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/)**

> The framework supports the development of language infrastructures including compilers and interpreters as well as full blown Eclipse-based IDE integration.

[image]

It includes code completion (as well as syntax highlighting, and many other Editor features).